# HTML popup window refering to its creator

Tags: html, popup, hyperlink, target

Supose I create a pop-up in `home.html` with something like:

```
<a href="somepage.html" target="_new">link</a>
```

How can I make a link **IN** somepage.html change the content of the browser
window/tab that contained the original link (the windows that has `home.html`)?

Can this be done by plain HTML? Or do I need JavaScript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need Javascript.

In somepage.html, you need a link like this:

```
<a href="javascript:window.opener.changeUrl('newpage.html');">
  link to newpage.html for the opening window
  </a>
```

and then in the home.html you need a function like so

```
function changeUrl(url) { document.location.href=url; }
```

that should do it!

Comment: Couldn't you just do "window.opener.location.href = 'newpage.html';" ?

Answer (score 1):

Only way I know how is with Javascript.  Use window.open to open the window.  In the popup, you should be able to reference it with window.opener

Comment: Thanks, these are basically the functions I needed :)